# Multiple Overlapping dates in multiple TSQL Rows needs to be reduced to a summary row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have a situation where the system we have creates multiple overlapping rows for login activity by end-users on the system. I have no idea why it does this but it does. I will add a few rows as an example below:

```
 RN2                  UserRegistryID LoginTime               LogoutTime              FinalLoginTime FinalLogoutTime
-------------------- -------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------- ---------------
1                    x89889         2018-05-15 12:56:30.000 2018-05-15 13:08:24.873                
2                    x89889         2018-06-26 09:08:59.000 2018-06-26 09:22:24.003                
3                    x89889         2018-06-26 09:22:58.000 2018-06-26 09:51:02.057                
4                    x89889         2018-11-09 12:50:58.000 2018-11-09 13:33:56.250                
5                    x89889         2019-02-12 13:16:17.000 2019-02-12 13:18:39.293                
6                    x89889         2019-02-12 13:19:38.000 2019-02-12 13:38:02.627                
7                    x89889         2019-02-19 13:52:00.000 2019-02-19 14:22:18.000                
8                    x89889         2019-02-19 14:23:34.000 2019-02-19 15:24:02.000                
9                    x89889         2019-03-03 13:20:52.000 2019-03-03 13:29:50.000                
10                   x89889         2019-03-03 13:30:25.000 2019-03-03 15:55:02.247                
11                   x89889         2019-06-21 12:19:35.000 2019-06-21 12:34:01.103                
12                   x89889         2019-09-17 07:55:06.000 2019-09-17 09:08:26.007                
13                   x89889         2019-09-19 20:22:40.000 2019-09-19 20:23:01.723                
14                   x89889         2019-09-21 23:21:43.000 2019-09-22 00:50:10.867                
15                   x89889         2019-09-23 00:16:50.000 2019-09-23 00:55:35.183                
16                   x89889         2019-10-13 22:35:43.000 2019-10-13 23:21:34.000                
17                   x89889         2019-10-13 23:16:29.000 2019-10-14 00:18:55.000                
18                   x89889         2019-10-14 00:16:09.000 2019-10-14 00:47:25.003                
19                   x89889         2019-10-14 12:24:24.000 2019-10-14 12:45:19.000                
20                   x89889         2020-01-07 15:07:42.000 2020-01-07 15:28:49.093                
21                   x89889         2020-01-29 14:29:41.000 2020-01-29 15:05:08.223                
22                   x89889         2020-02-10 12:31:04.000 2020-02-10 12:37:36.343                
23                   x89889         2020-03-17 19:10:31.000 2020-03-17 19:52:37.003                
24                   x89889         2020-03-24 15:23:47.000 2020-03-24 15:54:15.000                
25                   x89889         2020-03-24 16:31:42.000 2020-03-24 16:46:56.000                
26                   x89889         2020-03-25 21:04:43.000 2020-03-25 21:27:11.000                
27                   x89889         2020-03-25 21:45:56.000 2020-03-25 22:50:19.003                
28                   x89889         2020-03-26 01:39:16.000 2020-03-27 09:30:09.003                
29                   x89889         2020-03-26 18:15:36.000 2020-03-26 18:35:50.000                
30                   x89889         2020-04-09 18:47:32.000 2020-04-09 19:06:02.000                
31                   x89889         2020-04-16 19:13:57.000 2020-04-16 20:02:04.000                
32                   x89889         2020-04-24 09:13:07.000 2020-04-24 09:33:16.000
```

So the column RN2 sequences these events in the order they happen and the sequence is partitioned and incremental for every user - defined by the UserRegistryID. As you can see, the login time for the second row is before the logout time for the first row. The same is true for the third row. So by looking at this, you can deduce that this should be recognized as one "Session", Starting with the first row's LoginTime and the last row's LogoutTime. I have been trying to figure out how to approach this, and have tried a number of approaches, none successful. Does anyone have an idea of how I might achieve this?

Much appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: This seems like gaps and island question. What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Showing us your actual expected results, and giving us sample data we can use (not an image) will also help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. Here is one approach that uses `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()` to define groups of consecutive overlaping rows, that you can then aggregate:

```
select
    userRegistryID,
    min(rn2) min_rn2,
    max(rn2) max_rn2,
    min(loginTime) minLoginTime,
    max(logoutTime) maxLogoutTime,
    count(*) no_records
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when loginTime <= lagLogoutTime then 0 else 1 end)
            over(partition by userRegistryID order by rn2) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            lag(logoutTime) over(partition by userRegistryID order by rn2) lagLogoutTime
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by userRegistryID, grp
order by userRegistryID, minLoginTime
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to aggregate the rows but instead add the starting and ending dates of each session to each row, you can do:

```
select
    rn2,
    userRegistryID,
    loginTime,
    logoutTime,
    min(loginTime) over(partition by userRegistryID, grp) finalLoginTime,
    max(logoutTime) over(partition by userRegistryID, grp) finalLogoutTime
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when loginTime <= lagLogoutTime then 0 else 1 end)
            over(partition by userRegistryID order by rn2) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            lag(logoutTime) over(partition by userRegistryID order by rn2) lagLogoutTime
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
order by userRegistryID, rn2
```

Comment: Hi @GMB THank you for this. THe one problem with this, and also my fault for not clarifying is that there are other rows for the same user that would be a different session.I'll add all the data in an additional comment. And to answer your question, I would like to keep the rows but to just add the final session login and logout time in the last two columns.

Comment: @Larnu - I hope this helps, I have updated the original question to have text rather than an image. I originally tried a fw combinations of looking at he previous and next rows and flagging them, but that was before I realised you can have many rows where this is true. I figure the answer possibly lies with a nested while loop, but 1, I am running out of time and 2, I am not that clever!